# How do I show data in Tableau up to the current day in previous years for a financial year that starts in July

Tags: date, tableau-api, calculation

My issues is that I can't work out how to set a filter to only show data upto the current day in the current financial year for other financial years

Example
so its day 256 in this current financial year so I only want to show the data in the previous financial years up to day 256, how do I do this?

Help as my brain is about to explode..

Cheers,
Ben

I've tried filtering and formulas but they don't seem to work